# How can I expand context to an entire script?

Tags: python, scope, temporary-files

I am creating a class in Python and one of the methods needs to handle files and save them in a temporary directory. Once the method completes the temporary directory gets deleted. I need the temporary directory to be available to the entire script, as opposed to just the method.

```
import tempfile
import os

class sandbox:
    def start_tmp_dir():
        temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
        print('tmp dir available in start_tmp_dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(temp_dir.name)))
        return temp_dir.name

    def use_tmp_dir(dir_name):
        print('tmp dir available in use_tmp_dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(dir_name)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sandbox = sandbox
    dir_name = sandbox.start_tmp_dir()
    sandbox.use_tmp_dir(dir_name)
```

Output:

```
tmp dir available in start_tmp_dir: True
tmp dir available in use_tmp_dir: False
```

The Python manual [says this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryDirectory):

> On completion of the context or destruction of the temporary directory
>   object the newly created temporary directory and all its contents are
>   removed from the filesystem.

Which makes sense given the example I created. The docs also talk about using `with` and a context manager, but I can't seem to make either of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create instance of that class and use `self.temp_dir` and it will exist as long as object/instance exists.

```
import tempfile
import os

class Sandbox(): # uppercase - see "PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code"

    def start_tmp_dir(self): # self
        self.temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() # self.temp_dir
        print('tmp dir available in start_tmp_dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(self.temp_dir.name))) # self.temp_dir
        return self.temp_dir.name # self.temp_dir

    def use_tmp_dir(self, dir_name):
        print('tmp dir available in use_tmp_dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(dir_name)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sandbox = Sandbox() # uppercase and ()
    dir_name = sandbox.start_tmp_dir()
    sandbox.use_tmp_dir(dir_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For that to be true you need to use it as a context manager. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import tempfile
import os

class Sandbox(object):
    def __init__(self, temp_dir):
        self.temp_dir = temp_dir
        print('tmp dir available in constructor: ' + str(os.path.isdir(self.temp_dir)))

    def use_tmp_dir(self):
        print('tmp dir available in use_tmp_dir: ' + str(os.path.isdir(self.temp_dir)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        s = Sandbox(temp_dir)
        s.use_tmp_dir()
```